# how can i replicate admin.TabularInline outside of the admin (on the user side?)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Given a mode A and a model B that has a field with a many to many relationship with model A, I am trying to allow users creating an object of model B to also create an object of model A inline/on-the-fly just like TabularInline allows you to do on the admin.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem and the solution is not trivial (at least for the moment). Django admin uses Javascript(jQuery) to do this task. Multiplication of a form requires lots of altering values and IDs etc. But recently people started doing this with [htmx](https://htmx.org). The way it is done is explained in [this](https://justdjango.com/blog/dynamic-forms-in-django-htmx) article from JustDjango thoroughly. There is even a video tutorial about it. I personally like the way they do it. You can give it a try. It feels and looks like in the django admin. If you would like to do it purely in django, you can look up [formset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets)

Comment: Thanks! This htmx seems to be what I need...I am seeing from the article that the example is based on a foreignkey relationship. Do you know if it works on a manytomany as well?

Comment: Yes sure, it should work with ManyToMany as well. By the way, if the answer helped you, you can select it as accepted answer.

Comment: I’ll try Implement it ASAP!